# Unable to write data into the excel, excel is creating but it's corrupting

Tags: java, selenium

Unable to write data into the excel, excel is creating but it's corrupting
// Collecting all the Elements into the list

```
List<WebElement> atl=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@data-dojo-attach-point='_labelNode']"));
    int atls=atl.size();
    // Excel Work book creation
    File f= new File("D:\\kpmg\\data.xls");
    WritableWorkbook wwb=Workbook.createWorkbook(f);
    WritableSheet wsh=wwb.getSheet(0);
    for(int j=1;j<=atls;j++)
    {
        String z=atl.get(j).getText();
        Label l=new Label(j,2,z);
        wsh.addCell(l);
     }
    wwb.write();
    wwb.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code to write Excel file using POI

```
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(100);
    SXSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("output");
     FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("TestData.xlsx",true);

     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", (new File(".\\Resources\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe")).getAbsolutePath());
     WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");

    //Pass the Xpath which you required
    List<WebElement> Elements=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a"));
    int x=-1;
    for(WebElement ele: Elements)
    {
        System.out.println(ele.getText());
        SXSSFRow dataRow = sheet.createRow((short)++x);
        SXSSFCell cell=dataRow.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        cell.setCellValue(ele.getText());
    }      
}
```